# Drop down menu with php/mysql query - echoing information of selected item

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to create a drop down menu with PHP and echo the information of the selected item.

I can't figure out what code to put in the option line.

I have a MySQL table called: `peopletable`

The table has 3 columns: `id`, `name` and `group`. Multiple people can belong to the same group.

I'm trying to display the names of the people in group 5.

When a person is selected I would like to set a variable `$userid` to the id of the selected person.

Lower on the page I would then like to echo the id of this selected person.

Any help would be appreciated with this.

```
<form method="post" AUTOCOMPLETE="OFF" name="testsform">
<input type="Hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
<table>
    <tr>
        <div> 
            <select name="menuID" onchange="document.testsform.submit();">
                <option value="">Select a name... </option>
                <?php
                $query = "SELECT id, name FROM peopletable WHERE group=5 ORDER BY name";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Error in $query");
                while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                ?>

                    <option <!-- cannot figure this code out  --> </option>

                    <?php }?>
            </select>

                <?php if(isset($userid)){
                    echo $userid;
                    }
                ?>  
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can I ask. What does ? signify, and what does : signify.

Comment: Also, shouldn't I be added the words 'selected' somewhere?

Comment: sorry, just notice that you did write selected, I'll try this out

Comment: It's telling me that $userid is undefined

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$query =   "SELECT id, name 
            FROM peopletable 
            WHERE group=5 ORDER BY name";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Error in $query");
while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option value='{$info['id']}'>{$info['name']}</option>";

<?php 
}
?>
```

Now because the `<select>` has a `name='menuID'` you should get the id of the selected item in the dropdown in `$_POST['menuID']`

Comment: Thank you so much. I just needed to use the _POST code you described.

Comment: Last thing. Where do I put the 'selected code', so the selected value stays selected in the menu?

Comment: This worked for me:

    <option  
    <?php if ($_POST['menuID']==$info["id"]) {echo "selected";}?> 
    value="<?php echo $info["id"];?>"> 
    <?php echo $info["name"];?> </option>


Then I used $_POST['menuID'] to get the variable.